# Service Pack Setup Error VB6

Tags: visual-studio, vb6, service-pack

I am installing an old version of VB6. I had installed a previous version of the software, but uninstalled it. Now I get an error saying **'setup has detected that the service pack version of this system installed is newer that the update you are applying to it'.** I searched in the registry for the appropriate keys to modify, however I have not found same. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why would you want to replace a new SP with an older one?

Comment: No, i am just trying to install VB6 after it was uninstalled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which versions do you have installed of VB6 and of the servicepack?

I suggest you uninstall all VB6 related items, reboot, and then install VB6 again.

After that download servicepack 6 from [SP6 from the microsoft site](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5721) and install that.

If you are still having problems you might try to uninstall all versions of visual studio and install in order of release, so first install VB6 and then install VB.net

I did a reinstall on my machines several times (xp, w7-32b, x7-64b) and never had any problems, but I always installed VB6 first, then its SP6, and then Visual Studio (2005) with its servicepacks, and then checked the [windows update](http://www.update.microsoft.com/windowsupdate/v6/thanks.aspx?ln=en&&thankspage=5) to make sure I didn't miss anything.